# How to create a new column that indicating winner of a match given the results on two successive columns?

Tags: mysql

Suppose we have a table like :

```
MATCH_ID TEAM_ID   GOAL
123       1        4
123       2        1
126       1        1
126       3        2
```

I try to create a new column indicating the result of that match( winner = 1, looser = -1, draw = 0)

```
MATCH_ID TEAM_ID   GOAL   RESULT
123       1        4      1
123       2        1      -1
126       1        1      -1
126       3        2      1
```

Given these table structures what MySQL script would compute that result column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT x.*
     , CASE WHEN y.goals > x.goals THEN -1 
            WHEN y.goals < x.goals THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 END result 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.match_id = x.match_id 
   AND y.team_id <> x.team_id 
 ORDER BY match_id,team_id;
```

Comment: how can I edit you code if there is also the player column and to see total team_goal I need to aggreate on players column. So the result table will be same for the players of the same team

Comment: If you have a different question, edit the existing question, or ask a new one, but referencing back to this one.